# Detect a shape that is close to a circle using Hough in OpenCV

Tags: image-processing, opencv, geometry, detect, hough-transform

I'm still a beginner in OpenCV, and I'm trying to detect circles using HoughCircles with the following parameters:

```
HoughCircles(gray, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,2, gray.rows/8, 200, 90, 0, 130 );
```

However, `HoughCircles` is not detecting shapes that are closely similar to a circle, as in the image below.

Do you have an idea on how to fix such issue?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: so, try to play with those arguments - they are not universal.

Comment: Are your contours closed ? If so, use simple shape descriptors.

Comment: I see it detecting one almost-circle fine.  Is it supposed to detect all of them?  I'm not sure I understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hough is used to find near perfect circles. it is robust to holes and noise, but not to deformations.

You might want to try to find a measure of 'circle-likeness'. You could analyze the contours, by comparing the length vs the surface. If it is close to pi, you know you have a circular shape.

Comment: I was able to get it to recognize the football-shaped object in the image, but the asker wasn't able to clarify the question.